# How to use android library with native library as dependency for Chromium?

Tags: android, chromium, gn

I'm working on integrating some library (`aar` that contains native library (`.so`)) into Chromium (Snapdragon-optimized fork to be more detailed).

In order to use it in Android code i had to modify [`chrome/android/BUILD.gn`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/android/BUILD.gn) and add 2 dependencies:

```
deps = [
  ...
  "//third_party/libxyz_android:libxyz_android",
  "//third_party/libxyz_android:libxyz_android_settings",
  ...
]
```

So i had to create `third_party/libxyz` directory, put aar files there and create `BUILD.gn`:

```
import("//build/config/android/rules.gni")

android_aar_prebuilt("libxyz_android") {
  aar_path = "libxyz-android-release.aar"
#  proguard_configs = [ "src/proguard-gvr.txt" ]
  ignore_manifest = true  # Ignored because manifest merging is not supported (http://crbug.com/643967)
  ignore_native_libraries = false
}

android_aar_prebuilt("libxyz_android_settings") {
  aar_path = "libxyz-android-settings-release.aar"
  ignore_manifest = true  # Ignored because manifest merging is not supported (http://crbug.com/643967)
}
```

Note `ignore_native_libraries = false` as libxyz has native libaries.

While building of Chromium i got error:

> android_aar_prebuilt() with .so files is not supported. Use ignore_native_libraries = true to silence this error.

It comes from here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/build/config/+/master/android/rules.gni#2817

> assert(_ignore_native_libraries || !_scanned_files.has_native_libraries, ...

Is there any possibility to use `aar` with native libraries, some workaround or modified `rules.gni`? If i have to add the support myself - should i edit `rules.gni` and add native libraries copying from unzipped `aar` to target directory (it seems to be pretty simple)?

*Update 1*: i had to change target names and replace "-" to "_" because of target name error ("-" is not supported).

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: yes, i had to hack `android_rules.gni` to add support

Comment: can you post your solution?

Comment: Could you add your solution please? I'm working on this same issue. I've gotten it to copy to the output directory but its missing from the APK so I'm curious what you did differently. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `android_aar_prebuilt` in `//build/config/android/rules.gni` to copy the appropriate `.so` files into the build directory (`root_build_dir`).

Then you need to add a dependency on the AAR target to your `android_apk` target directly. Finally, also add the `.so` files in your build directory to the `loadable_modules` directive of `android_apk` (this is critical).

The [GN Reference](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs/reference.md) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation given here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/build/config/+/master/android/rules.gni#4119

Isn't .aar with .so is supported?